# How to calculate variance of Gaussian given mean and average deviation

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

I want to calculate the variance sigma of a Gaussian (normal) distribution given its mean mu and average deviation d (i.e. average of absolute value of difference from the mean). How can I do this?

If it makes any difference, for the particular case I'm looking at, the mean is 0, and I do know the number of observations n, though I suspect neither of these pieces of info is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For iid normal data, the expected mean deviation is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$.

For example, see [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_deviation#Average_absolute_deviation_.28general_form.29), the paragraph beginning "For the normal distribution, the ratio of mean absolute deviation to standard deviation..."

Also see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeanDeviation.html), which lists the result for the normal.

You can also get it from the mean of a [chi(1) distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution). (Note: chi, not chi-squared.)

The derivation isn't particularly hard to do from first principles, though.

Given that result, the square of the population mean-deviation is $\frac{2}{\pi}\sigma^2$. If the mean deviation is $d$, then $\sigma^2 = \frac{\pi}{2}d^2$.

[Of course, if you're doing it from *sample* statistics, I'm pretty sure this won't give an unbiased estimator.]

Comment: @baixiwei please note the correction above - I had left out the $^2$ off the $d$ in the last part.